# FlipClock javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to integrate [flipclock](http://flipclockjs.com/) timer on a webpage, which is going to countdown until tomorrow at 12 PM.

After getting it to work, I want to hide the Days, Hours and Minutes when the timer is less than a days, an hour a minute respectively

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bensjones/swjo7wjt/)

```
var date  = new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 5, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0));
var now   = new Date();
var diff  = date.getTime()/1000 - now.getTime()/1000;

var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true
});
```

What do I need to do

Comment: The plugin is called `FlipClock`, yet you're calling `FlipClip`. See the examples for basic setup info: http://flipclockjs.com/#basic-example. Are you sure there's no errors in the console?

Comment: what do you see on your page? can you create a fiddle of your page?

Comment: I don't see anything. Sure. I'll edit right now.

Comment: @mplungjan I looked into that thread and there's no solution.

Comment: So, what would be another method for achieving what I want ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bensjones/swjo7wjt/ I have this, and I want the time to be shown without the days category and still counting if user refreshes the page

Comment: `new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 5, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0));` is in June

Comment: Other than the date inconsistencies, your code works fine. As stated you just have the wrong method call: http://jsfiddle.net/ogafwg98/

Comment: and the wrong month: `var date  = new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 4, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0));`

Comment: Thank you guys. How will I be able to delete the days after there will be only 23:59 hours left ?

Comment: I mean, Supposing the countdown will go 23:59 hours from now on. There will still be `days: 00` on screen. Is there any possibility to have that cut off ?

Comment: Reopened and answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this - note the Date.UTC needs to reflect your 12 o'clock in your timezone - NOTE JS months start at 0 for January

```js
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 4, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0)), 
    now  = new Date(), 
    diff = date.getTime()/1000 - now.getTime()/1000,
    aDayInSecs=24*60*60, anHourInSecs=60*60, aMinuteInSecs=60;

if (diff<0) diff=200; // remove this line when happy

var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true,
    callbacks: {
        interval: function () {
            var time = clock.getTime().time;
            if (time < aDayInSecs) {
              var $days = $("span.days").nextUntil("span").andSelf();
              if ($days.length>0) $days.remove();  
            }
            if (time < anHourInSecs) {
              var $hours = $("span.hours").nextUntil("span").andSelf();
              if ($hours.length>0) $hours.remove();  
            }
            if (time < aMinuteInSecs) {
              var $min = $("span.minutes").nextUntil("span").andSelf();
              if ($min.length>0) $min.remove();  
            }
            if (time <= 1) {
              var $sec = $("span.seconds").next("ul").andSelf();
              if ($sec.length>0) $sec.remove(); 
              $(".clock").html("DONE");  
            }
        }
    }    
});
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://flipclockjs.com/_themes/flipclockjs/js/flipclock/flipclock.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://flipclockjs.com/_themes/flipclockjs/css/flipclock.css">
    
<br/><div class="clock"></div>
```

If you ALWAYS need tomorrow at 12, you can do

```
var date  = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()+1).setHours(12,0,0,0);
```